# Intern.io Run all tests in tests folder with regex

Tags: intern

How to run all tests scripts in tests folder with regex. In Mocha you can specify test.* and it will run all tests like test.a.js, test.b.js, etc.

`define({
    suites: [ 'tests/ndc' ],
    excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests)\//
});`

I need to replace [ 'tests/ndc' ] with regex how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no built-in support for wildcards or regex suite specifiers. The convention is to create a `tests/ndc/all.js` file and list all your suites in that, something like:

```js
define([
    './suite1',
    './suite2',
    './suite3'
], function () {});
```

Then in your intern config you just set suites to [ 'tests/ndc/all' ].